# Remove script itself

Tags: perl

I would like my script to remove itself automatically since its work is done. I have added the line below to the end of my script:

```
unlink($0);
```

For some reasons, it's not working. Could you please advise what I should do? Probably, there is another approach or I could add an error message to find out why it's not removed?

Thank you.

Comment: `unlink($0) or die "Cannot unlink $0: $!"; ` would print "some reasons".

Comment: Golly and we useta think self-MODIFYING code was bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you can't. It works in my machine. Maybe your file system locks the file when it's running.

And you please try this:

```
exec "rm -f '$0'";
```

which replace the current Perl process with the `rm` one. This should release your script and has it removed.

Answer (score 1):

at the end of your script:

```
system("sh -c 'sleep 1; rm -f $0' &");
```

Bit hacky, but why do you need to delete your script? Surely that means something has created it, why not have the creator delete it too?

Comment: It's just handy as sometimes people forget to remove scripts. If we did something on a production server by the script, in most cases it should be removed at the end of the work for the security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Your script is still running so the file will be in use, that's why it can't delete itself.

You need to call an external script to delete the first script after it has died.

Comment: It's possible to remove script itself using Bash, so I thought it would be possible to do same on Perl.

Comment: On most Windows like file systems this answer is true. On most Unix like file systems this answer is false. Some OS's try to apply their own expected file system behavior to all file systems, some try to apply the native file system behavior even if that is not what a program would expect.

Comment: Why in the world would the fact that it is running interfere with its unlinking itself? That just isn’t so.